# container_of sample code in lwn.net

Tags: c, linux-kernel

When seeing:

```
void my_object_release(struct kobject *kobj)
{
   struct my_object *mine = container_of(kobj, struct my_object, kobj);

   /* Perform any additional cleanup on this object, then... */
   kfree (mine);
}
```

in [LWN’s *The zen of kobjects*](https://lwn.net/Articles/51437/), it seems incorrect in the third parameter `kobj`. I think it should be `kobject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given code is correct: the third argument is the name of the container structure member to which the pointer points, not its type, so `kobj` is right. The example is somewhat confusing since the first `kobj` doesn’t correspond to the same thing as the second `kobj`: the first is the pointer in the caller’s scope.

Here’s a diagram to hopefully clarify the parameters of `container_of`:

```
container_of(kobj, struct my_object, kobj)
              |            |          |
              |            |          |
              \------------+----------+--------------------------------\
                           |          |                                |
                           |          |                                |
         /-----------------/          |                                |
         |                            |                                |
         V              /-------------/                                |
+------------------+    |                                              |
| struct my_object | {  |                                              |
+------------------+    V                                              V
                   +------+                                         +------+
    struct kobject | kobj |; <-- You have a pointer to this, called | kobj |
                   +------+                                         +------+
    ...
};
```

`container_of` allows you to pass around a `kobject` pointer and find the containing object (as long as you know what the containing object is) — it allows you to use your knowledge of “what” to answer “where”.

It’s worth pointing out that `container_of` is a macro, which is how it can do seemingly impossible things (for developers not used to meta-programming).

Comment: the third argument is the name of the container structure member to which the pointer points, not its type